# need help in a Qt Creator C++ app using Open GL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm writing an app in Qt Creator, using C++. The eventual goal is to have control over an OpenGL window from within the Qt main winow.

Initialization is fine, both mainwindow and OpenGL window start up with no issues.

The mainwindow is subclassed from QMainwindow, the OpenGL window is subclassed from public QWindow, public QOpenGLFunctions.

Here's the crux of the problem. I want event handlers in mainwindow to have access to the OpenGLWindow. I can't seem to make that happen. I've gotten past a number of obstacles so at this point I have the following set-up;

1. In main.cpp, I declare the objects for both mainwindow and OpenGLWindow. I have the mainwindow mousepressed event handler in main.cpp. As is, all works fine. Both windows come up as they should, and the event handler code does exactly what I want it to do in the mainwindow, just print some text in a textbox.
2. In order to have access to the openglwindow from the event handler in main.cpp, I declare the OpenGLWindow object as global, outside of the main () main.cpp (is this bad technique?).
3. Everything compiles fine, but when I run it I get the error 'QPixmap: Must construct a QGuiApplication before a QPixmap'. I assume that this means that the system is not happy that I am creating the OpenGLWindow before the application object.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Am I a few lines away from correct code, or does this need some major rearranging.

BTW - I am doing this in Windows 10. The main reason I have chosen Qt and OpenGL for this app is that I want it portable to Linux.

Comment: maybe you could provide your code? consider to check [ask]

Comment: There are three .cpp files, two .h files, and one .ui file. Are you suggesting that I copy and paste this code into my response? There doesn't seem to be an option to attach a .zipped folder.

Comment: no, don't copy the .zip file and also not in the comment. You should put the most important part of your code in your question before hand. Why? No one would figure out how to help, without reproducing it. Also check [example] (please really read this..)

Comment: You state `"I declare the OpenGLWindow object as global..."` -- that's the problem.  It will be constructed before `main` starts hence the warning.  Just declare it in `main` and pass a pointer (or reference) to it to your main window constructor.

Comment: That was it, I should have thought of using a pointer. Thank you! It's working without error now. I have another problem where the OpenGLWindow object is nor working, but I think I need to study more on how the binding to buffers work. Thank you again, take care!